# Drush ARD returning Some site subdirectories are not valid Drupal sites:

Tags: drupal-7, drush

I have a drupal 7 site that I am trying to migrate to Pantheon. I have done this in the past by using the drush ard command to archive the site. I am trying to do this now and I am getting an error. It does create an archive file, but the file does not include any themes or custom modules. The command I am running is

```
drush ard --destination "./archive.tar.gz"
```

and the error I get is

> Some site subdirectories are not valid Drupal sites: ./archive.tar.gz
>   [warning] Archive saved to C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\GrabABag/1
>   [ok] C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\GrabABag/1

It creates a file named 1 and if I use that in the migration it shows some content, but no theme and nothing from my custom modules. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The right command is:

drush ard --destination=./archive.tar.gz